# Link to vcruntime140.dll instead of vcruntime140_app.dll

Tags: c++-winrt

I found a way to do C#/C++ interop leveraging cpp winrt on desktop (without app containers), by bypassing the default Activation Factory resolution.

The way I do that, is by exposing native C++ functions as factories returning IUnknown pointers that I P/Invoke in C#, and then call Marshal.GetUniqueObjectForIUnknown(ptr) to get an RCW that I can cast to the WinRT interface.

The problem I have now, is that my C++ lib is linked to vcruntime140_app.dll instead of vcruntime140.dll, which makes this actually not redistribuable.
Is there a way to make a cppwinrt lib linking to the desktop C runtime ? (I use visual studio 2019 preview templates)

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting `AppContainerApplication` property to false seem to work.

I will certainly put something on github explaining my solution.